# Interpreting coefficient estimate of square rooted explanatory variable in multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I have a made-up linear model, and am interpreting the coefficient estimates. One of my prediction variables is square rooted, and I am struggling to work out an accessible interpretation.

My response variable is income, and my predictors are square rooted age and sex (binary, male=1, female=0). My coefficient estimates are 1 for the intercept, 0.05 for square rooted age and 1.5 for sex.

$$ income = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \sqrt{age} + \beta_2 sex + \epsilon $$

I understand the interpretation of the intercept estimate is that a female of age 0 has an income of £1 (a meaningless interpretation in this context), and the interpretation of the sex coefficient estimate is that men have £1.50 more income than women, of the same age. I however can't nicely put into words the square rooted relationship.

Are there any ideas to explain this result to a person with little statistical training?

Comment: Multivariate regression is more commonly reserved for regression analysis with multiple outcomes. Multiple predictors is just multiple regression.

Comment: @HeteroskedasticJim thank you for the correction, have edited accordingly!

Comment: For people who differ in square root age by one unit, if they have the same sex, they should differ in income by .05 pounds; higher age, higher income.